# How to separate ; into multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split, oracle11g

**How to separate ; into multiple rows in Oracle
Please Write the query in Oracle**

**NOTE:** The semicolon should take from input table which has more than 3 or 4..can extend upto n numbers..We can't assume it.It should separate semicolon into multiple rows

I have a table which looks as follows.

INPUT:

| ID | SENTENCE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | After hundreds of thousands;years - some sentence;the sentence/Perhaps our strongest way |
| 2 | dummy block of text;publishing and graphic design;fill gaps in the page;before the actual words / added |

The Output Should be:

| ID | SENTENCE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | After hundreds of thousands |
| 1 | years - some sentence |
| 1 | the sentence/Perhaps our strongest way |
| 2 | dummy block of text |
| 2 | publishing and graphic design |
| 2 | fill gaps in the page |
| 2 | before the actual words / added |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Need the query written in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, for sample data

```
SQL> with test (id, sentence) as
  2    (select 1, 'After hundreds of thousands;years - some sentence;the sentence/Perhaps our strongest way' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'dummy block of text;publishing and graphic design;fill gaps in the page;before the actual words / added' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select id,
  6    regexp_substr(sentence, '[^;]+', 1, column_value) sentence
  7  from test cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= regexp_count(sentence, ';') + 1
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by id, column_value;

        ID SENTENCE
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 After hundreds of thousands
         1 years - some sentence
         1 the sentence/Perhaps our strongest way
         2 dummy block of text
         2 publishing and graphic design
         2 fill gaps in the page
         2 before the actual words / added

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```